# CSS3 Animation not working on non-webkit browser

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-transitions

I want to create a CSS3 Animation that works on non-webkit browsers and webkit browsers. I included both CSS tags, but it refuses to work on Firefox. It works great on Chrome and Safari. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<svg>
    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
        <path stroke-dasharray="10,10" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M108.634,309.137c0.19-29.637,0.772-122.891,0.677-140.006c-0.112-20.395,6.424-61.949,66.966-61.949c40.273,0,65.163-0.552,77.294,0c24.892,1.132,34.114-11.41,37.47-19.581"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

CSS :

```
@keyframes antsAnimation {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%; 
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes antsAnimation  {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%; 
    }
}

svg {
    animation: antsAnimation 15s linear infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation: antsAnimation 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MpLwk/

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle. Have a look **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/MpLwk/2/)**

It appears that on mozilla you need to have a start and an end for the stroke-dashoffset...

```
from {
   stroke-dashoffset : 100%;
}
to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for firefox you will have to specify the following

```
@-moz-keyframes ANIMATION-NAME {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
@keyframes antsAnimation {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%; 
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes antsAnimation  {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%; 
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes antsAnimation  {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%; 
    }
}

svg {
    animation: antsAnimation 15s linear infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation: antsAnimation 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation: antsAnimation 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

You need to call the vendor specific tags